# change text object value of crystalreport dynamically

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I wanna change text object value of a crystalreport dynamically. and i used this code

```
PrintBillReceipt.SetParameterValue("?test", TextBox1.Text)
```

and it returns an error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." pointing "PrintBillReceipt.SetParameterValue"

imported CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine and CrystalDecisions.Shared

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of a text object dynamically, follow these steps:

1. Edit the report file and find out in which section is the text object located.
2. Find out the name of the text field. It can be found in the properties window after clicking the object.
3. For instance, if the object is located in Section2 (page header) and the object name is Text1, then use the below code to assign it a value from a TextBox which is located on your form.

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1
       Dim TextObject1 As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject =
           Report1.Section2.ReportObjects("Text1")

       TextObject1.Text = TextBox1.Text
       CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
   End Sub
   ```

**EDIT**

If the object is a parameter and not a text field then you should remove the question mark from "?test".

```
PrintBillReceipt.SetParameterValue("test", TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast report object to text object then set your text.

Here's an example:

```
Dim txtObj = TryCast(rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Item("Text1"), TextObject)
    txtObj.Text = TextBox1.Text
```